# MatTooltip show below html native dialog

Tags: angular, angular-components

Why MatTooltip show below html native dialog?

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'tooltip-overview-example',
  template: `
  <dialog #dialog style="height: 50px; opacity: 0.8">
    <button matTooltip="Test">test</button>
  </dialog>
  <button (click)="openDialog()">Open</button>`,
})
export class TooltipOverviewExample {
  @ViewChild('dialog') dialog: ElementRef<HTMLDialogElement>;
  openDialog() {
    this.dialog.nativeElement.showModal();
  }
}
```

Result

[image]

Demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3rx9ry?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftooltip-overview-example.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is expected because of the following:

1. `dialog` element uses `::backdrop` pseudo-element.

[image]
2. `matTooltip` uses Material CDK `overlay` which has `z-index` of `1000`

[image]

When an element has `::backdrop`, it becomes the `Top layer` which puts it outside of the `document` flow. This means that anything will always be rendered behind it unless a new `Top layer` element is added. Then the old `Top layer` element will be behind the new one, but still on top of the every other elements.

`z-index` has no effect on element that is a `Top layer`.

Read more:

- [Top-layer](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/what-is-the-top-layer/).
- [::backdrop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::backdrop).